# NetBeans: JavaDoc is never shown

Tags: java, netbeans, javadoc, netbeans-7, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am having a big issue. That is I am using NetBeans 7.1.2, and it never show me the JavaDoc instantly, when I type some method, it searches for the JavaDoc  in the internet saying "Downloading JavaDoc". Then only it shows the JavaDoc for the method. I even tried downloading the JavaDoc manually and setting it to the netbeans, but still no good. Following images will explain the issue clearly.

[image: JavaDoc is not instant. It is downloading]

[image: JavaDoc is added Manually]

Here, JavaDoc is downloading
Here, JavaDoc is added manually

Comment: what do you mean by JavaDock? i think what you realy mean is JavaDoc as in java documentation right?

Comment: Ohh goodness, Yes..JavaDoc..Sorry for the issue

Comment: Did you tried to add URL : `http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`?

Comment: wow. It was there before I add the JavaDoc manually. Then I removed it to avoid JavaDoc downloading. Seems like it MUST be there! Thanks a lot for your help, it worked! And please, add this answer as an "Answer" then only I can give you an upvote and choose your answer as the correct one :)

Comment: Thanks, glad it has helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add URL : `http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/`